# Make a button dynamic with Repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have this Repeater control so i want to add a button which will download according to what ever item i have clicked so far i have this
how can i make the download button dynamic

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <h4>
            <asp:Label ID="title" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("title")%>'>
                <asp:Image ID="musicimage" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image_src")%>' runat="server" Height="150" Width="150" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" />
        </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This is my C# code
 so when i click the button this code runs

```
protected void btnDownload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String FileName = title; //from the db
    String FilePath = image_src //source from the db
    System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.ClearContent();
    / response.Clear();
    response.ContentType = "audio/mpeg";
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ";");
    response.TransmitFile(FilePath);
    response.Flush();
    response.End();
}
```

Comment: Link button works best with repeater.  
Then use repeater itemcommand to handle the button click.  

Make sure to bind the repeater on pageload and on page prelender to.  Hop this help you

Comment: can you show me an example please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try below code to get music download
aspx code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <h4>
            <asp:Label ID="title" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("title")%>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:Image ID="musicimage" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image_src")%>' runat="server" Height="150" Width="150" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" CommandName="DownloadMusic" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and in code behind means in .cs page

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "DownloadMusic")
    {
        //To get title of music
        string Title = string.Empty;
        Label lbltitle = new Label();
        lbltitle = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("title");
        Title = lbltitle.Text;

        //to get path fo music
        string FilePath = string.Empty;
        Image imgfile = new Image();
        imgfile = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("musicimage");
        FilePath = imgfile.ImageUrl;


        System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.ClearContent();
        response.ContentType = "audio/mpeg";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Title + ";");
        response.TransmitFile(FilePath);
        response.Flush();
        response.End();
    }
}
```

Try this.

Comment: so i made a label to test if i am able to get the `FilePath ` but nothing happens

Comment: try this one and let me know you are able to get lable value or not

Comment: are you binding some data to repeater control right? can you please post that part here

Comment: can you please put your repeater binding code ins side if(!IsPostBack) in page_Load event

Comment: i have changed this part to `false`
`<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> `
because when its true it gives an error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143097/discussion-between-kevin-shah-and-craftx398).

Comment: In the code above try to change the button to linkbutton. and bind the DataSource to repeater each time page_Load fire. then when you click the button it have to be a full post back. that mean it cant be inside updatepanel, else add a postback trigger to updatePanel